# How to quit Illustrator and ExtendScript Toolkit from a script?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I use a .jsx script to open an Illustrator file, modify it, then save and close it.
The script is called from another program.
After the script execution, I need to quit both Illustrator and ExtendScript Toolkit softwares. I tried the following code:

```
    [...]
    document.close();
    app.quit(); // quitting Ai
```

Illustrator exits well after the script execution but ExtendScript Toolkit application is still opened, even if the script is terminated.

I call my script from a Windows command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe" "C:\Users\user\Documents\Adobe Scripts\script.jsx"
```

So, does anyone know how to quit the ExtendScript Toolkit window from the script (or anywhere else).

Once the script is terminated, I could see in the data explorer window, I see an app object named 'ExtendScript Toolkit' with a .quit() function, but I can't call it from the script because while executing 'app' is still Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I'm not sure what the #target is for ESTK. I've tried ESTK, extendscript, so not sure. If ExtendScript has an alias, I'm certain that once you target it you can quit without issue.

---

Alright so this is how to do it.

```
#target illustrator
//do stuff
app.quit()
#target estoolkit
//do stuff
app.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, targetting 'estoolkit' works. But it seems you can't target 2 applications in a same script. When I target both illustrator and estoolkit, only estoolkit quits, and some Illustrator specific functions are undefined. So, I have splitted the script into one for each application and it works very well. Anyway, it's cleaner than killing the ESTK process as I did until now :)